# How to automatically calculate/update a due date in a maintenance table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a maintenance table that stores a maintenance contract's startDate, frequency, and frequencyUOM(i.e years, months, days).
How am I able to automatically calculate the next due date of a maintenance contract once the old due date passes?

This is for a preventative maintenance application I'm building in asp.net with c#. So I need the due dates to order by in tables I've set up. Would i want to do this via C# or a SQL stored procedure?

I'm not sure where to begin with this so any kick in the right direction is appreciated and I apologize for my lack of code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of SQL?

Comment: Maybe just a simple SQL Job to check the dates and update them when needed.

Comment: Or edit your table to have a NextDueDate set of columns, and when your old one expires, use the new one until the Job can update the old due date with the new one and then calculate the next. Depends on how often you need to run the Job. Probably better to just run the Job after hours and update dates for the next day. Unless you're a 24 hour operation.

Comment: i think you could do this with a calculated column in a view.

Comment: @Shawn it is mySQL syntax I'm pretty sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server [you could create a recurring job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-2017) that updates the `NextDueDate` column. Or find something similar in your respective SQL database. Otherwise, you could create a simple service in C# that does the same thing.

I'm wondering though if it would be better to have two tables, one for `Contracts` and one for `Bills` with a 1 to many relationship. So if a contract was created for 1 year with 12 monthly payments, you'd generate 1 `Contract` row and 12 `Bill` rows, and have a boolean column called `IsPaid` for the `Bills` table. This way you have traceability for every expected servicing or bill.

Then, you could have a view that has columns with `Contract` data, and a calculated `NextDueDate` column that gets the calculation of respective bills ordered by date, lowest one greater than current date.